# Finding elements in SQL statement list

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking at SQL statements as strings and want to count the number of elements in the largest list in the SQL query. For example, the following string would have a max count of 5:

```
"select id from table where language in (\"ENGLISH\", \"SPANISH\", \"german\") and id in (1,2,3,4,5);"
```

Does anyone know how to do this using regex? It's tricky because the contents of the list might be integers, strings, or tuples. The best I've been able to come up with is the following:

Use https://regex101.com/r/iNOxuO/1 to first match all lists in the string. Then, for each of those matches, run https://regex101.com/r/kowtrV/1 to match and count each element in the list.

The problem I'm having is that there are a few edge cases (the last two lines in the first link) that are escaping me.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem beyond that? Trying to do dynamic set matches as parameterized input? Seems like you're asking about your attempted solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to write some separate expressions for your edge cases, then use alternation, and then you'll be adding a counter. The start core expression would be something as simple as:

```
(?<=\(|,)[^,]+?(?=\)|,)
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/rPCCDU/1)

Then, when you write those others, imagine

```
 some other expression 1
```

and

```
  some other expression 2
```

You would join them with logical ORs:

```
some other expression 1| some other expression 2|(?<=\(|,)[^,]+?(?=\)|,)
```

You'll figure it out which expression has to be prior. It is just time-consuming to write all those expressions.